# javascript object in anonymous function tag trigger

Tags: javascript

i have made an tag trigger function inside an anonymous function , here it is :

```
(function(){
  var getElement = {
    getElem: function(element , elemInterval){
      if(document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].onload){
        element = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
        clearInterval(elemInterval);
        element.innerHTML = ' content changed. ';
      }
    }
  }
  var element , elemInterval;
  elemInterval = setInterval(getElement.getElem(element , elemInterval) , 1000);
})();
```

what it got to do is to call a function as many time as it needs every one second and check if the first div as been loaded , than it save the element port to the "element" var and change the content of the div.

this seems to not work , what's the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling it directly and passing the *result value* to `setInterval`, which is `undefined`.

What you probably want is passing a *function* to `setInterval`, which in turn will call `getElem`:

```
elemInterval = setInterval(function() {
                               getElement.getElem(element , elemInterval);
                           }, 1000);
```

Comment: I've tried it but it actually doing nothing , here is a live example : http://jsfiddle.net/NGnEd/

Comment: @Mor Sela: That's because of your `if` clause. Why do you check for `onload`? http://jsfiddle.net/NGnEd/1/

Comment: that's awesome man ! i though that the onload should give me true if it have been loaded , but i guess i was wrong , thank men.

Comment: @Mor Sela: No, you're checking whether the element has an `onload="..."` attribute, which is not really meaningful here.

Answer (score 1):

You call the function immediately and pass `undefined` (its return value) as the first argument of `setInterval`. Learn how closures work.

```
elemInterval = setInterval(function() {
    getElement.getElem(element , elemInterval);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I've tried it but it actually doing nothing , here is a live example : http://jsfiddle.net/NGnEd/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that of scope - the getElem function is contained in a var, which is contained in the function block (which has a scope of its own as well). Interval functions need to be accessible in the global scope.

I'm not able to test this right now, but iirc, this would work:

```
var something = (function(){
  var getElement = {
    getElem: function(element , elemInterval){
      if(document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].onload){
        element = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
        clearInterval(elemInterval);
        element.innerHTML = ' content changed. ';
      }
    }
  }
  var element , elemInterval;
  elemInterval = setInterval(something.getElement.getElem(element , elemInterval) , 1000);
  return getElement;
})();
```

But that's a high level of indirection, you might want to avoid containing your function in another nested function.

Comment: why you return this object in the end?

Comment: Because that's what gets assigned to 'var something' - without the return, something contains the function definition instead of the getElement object with the getElem method.